# Bug? "SELECT LEFT JOIN" match all rows, but "UPDATE LEFT JOIN" ignores some. Example inside

Tags: mysql, sql-update, left-join, primary-key, rows-affected

I want to update two tables with one UPDATE query. I use a simple LEFT JOIN for that. Curiously not all matching rows are changed. This are the example tables:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test_continents`, `test_agents`;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test_continents` (
  `key` char(2) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`key`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=FIXED;

INSERT INTO `test_continents` (`key`) VALUES('EU');
INSERT INTO `test_continents` (`key`) VALUES('NA');


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test_agents` (
  `name` char(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `continent` char(2) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`name`),
  KEY `continent` (`continent`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=FIXED;

INSERT INTO `test_agents` (`name`, `continent`) VALUES('006', 'EU');
INSERT INTO `test_agents` (`name`, `continent`) VALUES('007', 'EU');
INSERT INTO `test_agents` (`name`, `continent`) VALUES('008', 'NA');
INSERT INTO `test_agents` (`name`, `continent`) VALUES('009', 'NA');

OPTIMIZE TABLE `test_continents`, `test_agents`;
```

This is the sample SELECT query, it does match all rows:

```
SELECT

`test_agents`.`continent`,
`test_agents`.`name`

FROM `test_continents`

LEFT JOIN `test_agents` ON (
    `test_agents`.`continent` = `test_continents`.`key`
)

WHERE

`test_continents`.`key` = 'NA'
```

This is the UPDATE query:

```
UPDATE `test_continents`

LEFT JOIN `test_agents` ON (
    `test_agents`.`continent` = `test_continents`.`key`
)

SET

`test_continents`.`key` = 'SA',
`test_agents`.`continent` = `test_continents`.`key`

WHERE

`test_continents`.`key` = 'NA'
```

After the update, the tables look like this:

test_continents:

```
key
EU
SA
```

test_agents:

```
name   continent
006    EU
007    EU
008    SA
009    NA
```

Can anyone explain me why the continent field for test_agent 009 is still 'NA' after the UPDATE?

It seems that this does not happen if I use INT fields, but I need CHAR(2) fields, so please don't discuss about the table structure, just say me is this a bug, a feature or anything else?

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and MySQL 5.5.29-1~dotdeb.0 I am coder since more than 15 years and normaly I don't ask such lamer questions but I can not explain it and I need help...

**UPDATE:**

I have made a second example with INT(2) fields instead of CHAR(2). The UPDATE match all rows in this case:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test_agents` (
  `name` char(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `continent` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`name`),
  KEY `continent` (`continent`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=FIXED;

INSERT INTO `test_agents` (`name`, `continent`) VALUES('006', 1);
INSERT INTO `test_agents` (`name`, `continent`) VALUES('007', 1);
INSERT INTO `test_agents` (`name`, `continent`) VALUES('008', 2);
INSERT INTO `test_agents` (`name`, `continent`) VALUES('009', 2);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test_continents` (
  `key` int(2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`key`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=FIXED;

INSERT INTO `test_continents` (`key`) VALUES(1);
INSERT INTO `test_continents` (`key`) VALUES(2);
```

--

```
SELECT

`test_agents`.`continent`,
`test_agents`.`name`

FROM `test_continents`

LEFT JOIN `test_agents` ON (
    `test_agents`.`continent` = `test_continents`.`key`
)

WHERE

`test_continents`.`key` = 2
```

--

```
UPDATE `test_continents`

LEFT JOIN `test_agents` ON (
    `test_agents`.`continent` = `test_continents`.`key`
)

SET

`test_continents`.`key` = 3,
`test_agents`.`continent` = `test_continents`.`key`

WHERE

`test_continents`.`key` = 2
```

test_agents after the UPDATE:

```
name   continent
006    1
007    1
008    3
009    3
```

--

I can not believe that this is a normal behavior. The only difference between both examples is the field type, so it should affect the same rows or not? I am sure the queries are 100% correct.

Has anyone an explanation???

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm guessing `test_agents.continent` gets set to the old value of `test_continents.key`. Which means there is no change at all given the JOIN condition.

Comment: I am sure my query is correct. Please look at my 2nd example with INT(2) keys. In this example all matching rows are updated. The only difference is the field type. I can not believe that this is the correct behavior. It is illogical.

Comment: The only solution I can think of is to avoid updating the field which is used for a join in the same query. It is likely that this is documented as undefined behavior anyway.

Comment: After some testing I found out that CHAR(2) works correct if the fields are defined as ascii_general_ci. This solves my problem. I think it is a bug caused by character set...

Comment: UPDATE with JOIN is not standard SQL. The syntax is inherently flawed/inconsistent (a problem common to other DBMSs that attempt the same thing - not just MySQL). You can avoid it by using the safe and standard ISO syntax with a derived table subquery.